# Having trouble connecting to wcf service on localhost from Android emulator

Tags: c#, android, wcf, iis, iis-express

I'm building an app with Xamarin Studio that's supposed to access a wcf service. Accessing the service works fine from my browser with the following url:
`http://localhost:52277/api`

Whenever I try to access it from my android code, I get the following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Exception: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.ServiceClientBase.Send[String] (System.String httpMethod, System.String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, System.Object request) [0x00051] in c:\Users\nicklas.winger\Documents\GitHub\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\ServiceClient.Web\ServiceClientBase.cs:896
```

I'm running the service on IIS express, and I've modfied my iis applicationhost.config like this (Removing 'localhost' from bindingInformation, according to a course on pluralsight):

```
<site name="ProteinTrackerMvc" id="45">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\users\nicklas.winger\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ProteinTrackerMvc\ProteinTrackerMvc" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52277:" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

Also, my web service is building and deploying using iis express at the mentioned port.
Any suggestions to what I might be doing wrong? :)

Comment: Check out http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: @NicklasWinger Note: ServiceStack clients are only for consuming ServiceStack services, not WCF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by using the following ip:
10.0.2.2 instead of localhost.

Comment: I solved changed localhost for ip of my webservice too. Thanks :)

Comment: i never thought this would work. But how should I know?

Comment: is the this ip of your pc or the android emulator? and where you change it? thanks

Comment: I would assume my computer at the time. Kind of blurry, as this post is approx. 4 years old :/